# SICP exercise 1.41

Tags: python, algorithm, debugging

> **Exercise 1.41.** Define a procedure double that takes a procedure of one argument as
>   argument and returns a procedure that applies the original procedure
>   twice. For example, if inc is a procedure that adds 1 to its argument,
>   then `(double inc)` should be a procedure that adds 2. What value is
>   returned by `(((double (double double)) inc) 5)`

I implemented it in Python.

```
def double(f):
    print(f)
    return (lambda x: (f(f(x))))

def inc(x):
    return x+1

print(double(inc)(0))
print((double(double))(inc)(0))
print((double(double(double)))(inc)(0)
```

Output:

```
<function inc at 0x00000000029BBB70>
2
<function double at 0x0000000002141730>
<function inc at 0x00000000029BBB70>
<function double.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000029BBC80>
4
<function double at 0x0000000002141730>
<function double.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000029BBD08>
<function inc at 0x00000000029BBB70>
<function double.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000029BBBF8>
<function double.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000029BBD90>
<function double.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000029BBE18>
16
```

My questions are:

1. Why the output of `print((double(double(double)))(inc)(0)` is 16 instead of 8?
2. Why the function of `double` was called 3 times instead of 2 times when run `(double(double))(inc)(0)`
3. Are there any debug tools that can set breakpoints in python like "gdb" in C so that I can debug this program?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `pdb` (`import pdb; pdb.Pdb().set_trace()` is a "breakpoint") or a Python-supporting IDE such as PyCharm ("community edition" is now free).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze your code:

```
print( double(inc)(0) )
```

So this will call the function `double` with argument `inc`. So as expected, it will return a function which will apply the function `inc` twice on an argument. So you will get 2 as the output. You have done this correctly.

Now, the interesting point is here:

```
print( (double(double))(inc)(0) )
```

Note that you have call the function `double` with the argument `double`, and then call the resulting function with the argument `inc`. So this is what happen:

1. call `double(double)` # that is, `double` with argument `double` (first call to `double`)
2. you get a function which will call `double` two times on the argument
3. you use that function on `inc`.
4. so you get a function which will apply `double` two times to `inc` (there are two times of calls to `double` here)

What you get is a function that will increment by 4. And actually this is not 2*2, but rather 2^2, it just coincidence (or not) that 2^2 = 2*2 = 4, so you still get answer of 4.

The third print:

```
print((double(double(double)))(inc)(0)
```

Actually you call `double` on the result of `double(double)`, which will apply the function `double(double)` twice on itself. So effectively you're calling `double(double)(double(double(inc)))`. So you apply the function `inc` 2*2*(2*2) = 16 times.

To get better understanding of this, note that:

```
print( double(double(double(inc)))(0) )
```

will print 8.

Answer (score 2):

As others already answered the main points, here is an improved version of your code that shows the execution flow with descriptive functions names:

```
def double(f):
    print('double({})'.format(f))
    def _f(x):
        print('{}({})'.format(_f.__name__, x))
        return f(f(x))
    _f.__name__ = 'double_{}'.format(f.__name__)
    return _f

def inc(x):
    return x + 1

print(double(inc)(0))
print((double(double))(inc)(0))
print((double(double(double)))(inc)(0))
```

The output:

```
double(<function inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa578>)
double_inc(0)
2
double(<function double at 0x7fb3a9ffa500>)
double_double(<function inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa578>)
double(<function inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa578>)
double(<function double_inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa6e0>)
double_double_inc(0)
double_inc(0)
double_inc(2)
4
double(<function double at 0x7fb3a9ffa500>)
double(<function double_double at 0x7fb3a9ffa7d0>)
double_double_double(<function inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa578>)
double_double(<function inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa578>)
double(<function inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa578>)
double(<function double_inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa8c0>)
double_double(<function double_double_inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa938>)
double(<function double_double_inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa938>)
double(<function double_double_double_inc at 0x7fb3a9ffa9b0>)
double_double_double_double_inc(0)
double_double_double_inc(0)
double_double_inc(0)
double_inc(0)
double_inc(2)
double_double_inc(4)
double_inc(4)
double_inc(6)
double_double_double_inc(8)
double_double_inc(8)
double_inc(8)
double_inc(10)
double_double_inc(12)
double_inc(12)
double_inc(14)
16
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `double` applies its argument to itself, as you clearly indicate with:

   ```
   lambda x: f(f(x))
   ```

   So what's `double(double(double))` ? It must be

   ```
   (double(double))(double(double))
   ```

   So, 16 times.
2. `double(double)` uses a call to `double` to produce `lambda f: double(double(f))`. Applying that to some `f` (`inc` in this case) requires two calls to `double`. So that's a total of three.
3. I don't know if `gdb` would have actually helped you here. Pencil and paper [β-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Beta_reductio) is not that difficult in this case, and quite possibly more revealing.

Good luck with SICP!